# How can I pass a model into custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My goal is to pass the projectName model from my MainController to my custom contenteditable directive.

I have the following controller:

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope){
    $scope.projectName = "Hot Air Balloon";
});
```

Here is how I'm calling the directive:

```
<div class="column" ng-controller="MainController">
    <h2 contenteditable name="myWidget" ng-model="projectName" strip-br="true"></h2>
    <p>{{projectName}}</p>
</div>
```

I've gotten the contenteditable directive working by following this tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

If I understand the docs correctly then Angular is not going to use the model I want it to.  Instead its going to create a new model w/ scope local to the contenteditable directive.  I know that I can add an isolate scope to the directive but I don't know how to use the model passed to the isolate scope within the link function.

I have tried something like the following which didn't work ...

```
<h2 contenteditable item="projectName"></h2>
```

--- directive code ---

```
scope: {
    item: '=item'
}

link: function(){
    ...
    item.$setViewValue(...)
    ...
}
```

--- my original directive call --

```
<div class="column" ng-controller="MainController">
    <h2 contenteditable name="myWidget" ng-model="projectName" strip-br="true"></h2>
    <p>{{projectName}}</p>
</div>
```

--- my original controller and directive ---

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope){
    $scope.projectName = "LifeSeeds";
});

app.directive('contenteditable', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
            console.log(ngModel);

            if(!ngModel) return;

            console.log(ngModel.$viewValue);

            ngModel.$render = function(){
                element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
            };

            element.on('blur keyup change', function(){
                scope.$apply(read);
            });
            read();

            function read(){
                var html = element.html();
                if(attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>'){
                    html = '';
                }
                ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
            }

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: In the pastebin linked below I am using an isolate scope in place of passing a model to the link function.  The page now loads with MainController's projectName model's value set in the editable but updating the field still does not change the value of the model.  The model's value remains "LifeSeeds" no matter what.  I can't find documentation anywhere to this working.  http://pastebin.com/XMzsGYSv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/Lu1ZG9Lpx2sl8CYe8FCx?p=preview

I mentioned that I tried using an isolate scope in my original post.

```
<h2 contenteditable item="projectName"></h2>
```

This was actually the correct approach so ignore my full original example using the model argument of the directive's link function.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel)
```

The reason the isolate scope approach did not work was because $scope.projectName stored a primitive instead of an object.  I did not understand some javascript basics.  Mainly, I did not know that primitive types were passed to functions by value.

Primitives are passed by value in javascript.  Consequently, changes made to primitive values within a function do NOT change the value of the variable passed to the function.

```
function changeX(x){
    x = 5;
}
x = 4;
changeX(x);
console.log(x) // will log 4 ...  Not 5
```

However, objects passed to functions in javascript are passed by reference so modifications to them within the function WILL be made to the variable passed into the function.

My problem was in how I declared the scope within the MainController.

I had:

```
$scope.projectName = "LifeSeeds";
```

That's a primitive.  When I passed projectName to the directive I was passing a primitive.

```
<h2 contenteditable item="projectName"></h2>
```

Thus, changes to the editable element were being made to the value within the directive but not to the value stored in the MainController's scope.  The solution is to store the value within an object in the MainController's scope.

```
// correct
$scope.project = {
    html: "Editable Content"
};

// wrong
$scope.projectName = "Editable Content"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-model with your own directive. To make sure it is included, you can use the attribute `require` like this:

`app.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return {
        require:"ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
                console.log(ngModel);
            }
    }
});`

Then, you can code whatever behavior your want of ng-model within your directive.

Comment: This is what I had before I posted and I think its the correct way to do it.  This is what I'm seeing in the console: {$viewValue: NaN, $modelValue: NaN, $parsers: Array[0], $formatters: Array[0], $viewChangeListeners: Array[0]…}...  It appears that the correct model is being passed in.  I guess the problem I'm having has to do with the rendering function I copied from the tutorial.  I think its overwriting the model's value.  Am I correct?  On a side note, the tutorial uses require:"?ngModel".  I'm guessing the question mark is a typo since I haven't seen it anywhere else (yet).

Comment: The question mark is not a typo, it means ngModel is optional. Can you edit your question and add your old code so I can take a look at it?